# Create a new instance of a class, call a method, and cast its return value in a single line

Tags: c#

Is it possible create a new instance of a class, call a method, and cast its return value in a single line?

I am trying to do the following in a single line:

```
var converter = new ColorConverter();
return (Color)converter.ConvertFromString("#FFDFD991");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return (Color)(new ColorConverter()).ConvertFromString("#FFDFD991");
```

From what I see, it looks like ConvertFromString() could probably be made into a static method, in which case you could simply call it like this:

```
return (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFDFD991");
```

Comment: Unfortunately ColorConverter is a class in System.Drawing and does not have it as a static method.  I thought the same.  Thanks for the syntax!